# How to manage custom attributes in group customer

Tags: customer-group, magento2.2, group, repository, attribute-group

i'm new in the magento world (and php community).
I want to add some attributes to custom group in magento 2.2

I've created a new attribute by setup (his name is : 'exchange_id') :

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.2') < 0) {
            $this->upgradeTo002($installer);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }

    protected function upgradeTo002(SchemaSetupInterface $installer)
    {
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('customer_group');

        $columns = [
            'exchange_id' => [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Exchange id'
            ],
        ];
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
            $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

The customer group is created but not the extra data (like exchange_id).

```
/**
 * @var Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory;
 */
private $groupFactory

/**
 * @var Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;
 */
private $groupRepository

public function createGroup($groupCode, $exchangeId, $taxClassId)
{
    $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
    $group
        ->setCode($groupCode)
        ->setTaxClassId($taxClassId);
    $group->setData('exchange_id', $exchangeId);

    $this->groupRepository->save($group);

    return $group->getId();
}
```

[image: Cutomer group entity in db]

The save method from groupRepository (in magento2) recreate another group for saving the group. And he lost the others data :

In mangento 2.2 (line131) : Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\GroupRepository (who implements \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface)

```
        $groupModel = $this->groupFactory->create();
        $groupModel->setCode($group->getCode());

        $taxClassId = $group->getTaxClassId() ?: self::DEFAULT_TAX_CLASS_ID;
        $this->_verifyTaxClassModel($taxClassId, $group);
        $groupModel->setTaxClassId($taxClassId);
```

Thanks !